# Building a Dynamic Menu Based On Laravel 5 Models & Blade Templates

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, menu

I have a database table for storing all menu elements for a sites main menu...

```
id (int)
caption (string)
route (string)
status (long text)
parent (int)
```

What I want to be able to do is access the menu through a Laravel model on each page load regardless of the route requested and add it to the underlying blade template to build the main menu from the database.

I can output everything from the menu into a single list using standard Model examples from Laravel but can't seem to find any examples or direction on how to do a multi-level menu system such as...

- Home
- Services

  - Service 1
  - Service 2
  - Service 3
- Products

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3
- About Us

Have no idea where to start on how to achieve this using Laravel models and blade templates.

Comment: Why don't you first try and retrieve all the items from the table whose `parent` is `null`. Then retrieve their respective child menu items?

Comment: For performance reasons want to try to do the whole menu in one query. Would like to pull all menu items and restructure as a multi-level array and then run over it in the blade template